# How to disable unchecked checkbox and checked checkbox can be toggle? in ngFor loop in angular 8?

Tags: angular, typescript

```
<div id="col-container">
    <mat-card id="profile-card" *ngFor="let candidate of obj_users; let i = index;  ">
        <img class=" candidates-image" mat-card-image src="{{candidate.photo }}" />
        <mat-card-content>
            <h3 style="margin-bottom: 8px;"> {{ candidate.firstname }}
                {{ candidate.lastname}} </h3>
            <!-- <p *ngIf=""> PRESIDENT </p> -->
            <p> {{ candidate.position_id }} </p>
            <mat-divider [inset]="true"></mat-divider>
            <p> {{ candidate.platform }}</p>
            <p> {{ candidate.nation }}</p>
            <label class="switch">
                <input [disabled]="disabledButton" (change)="OnChange($event , i)" id="checkbox" type="checkbox">
                <span matRipple id="purecbx">VOTE</span>
            </label>
        </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
</div>
```

Comment: Please can you clarify your question?

Comment: can you put it into https://codesandbox.io/ ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a property in the obj_users as disabledButton so that every candidate has a property disableButton and you can make every buuton disable and manage it's statues as checked separately

```
<label class="switch">
       <input [disabled]="candidate.disabledButton" (change)="OnChange($event , i)" id="checkbox" type="checkbox">
       <span matRipple id="purecbx">VOTE</span>
</label>
```

To make the checkbox enable set that index of the obj_users disableButton property to false so that the user can check and uncheck